# Capybara - test for bad data

Tags: rspec, capybara

Let's say I have a radio button

```
<input type="radio" name="test" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="test" value="2">
```

I want to test against "hackers" and I want to submit "3". 
Is there a way to do so in Capybara + Rspec?

Comment: wouldn't you test that your controller handles invalid inputs correctly instead?

Comment: The problem is that I'm actually testing PHP code with Capybara - i.e. external code. There is no way to call controller, except for HTTP request.